# Detection of a new/delete fingerprint enrolment

Tags: android, google-drive-shared-drive

I am currently working in fingerprint authentication from [https://github.com/googlesamples/android-FingerprintDialog] in my app but I'm not able to detect in any new fingerprint added or deleted. I'm looking for a callback/event whenever changes happened in fingerprint manager.

My understanding of KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is that it’s thrown when e.g. a fingerprint was deleted or a new fingerprint was added in the device settings. I’m getting that exception only if

1. open an app, the keys are created by mKeyGenerator.generateKey();
2. confirm a fingerprint
3. minimise the app
4. open settings and add a new fingerprint
5. come back to the app and try to authenticate again a new KeyPermanentlyInvalidatedException is thrown

However if the point 3 is replaced by “exit the app“ and I follow the next steps, the exception is not thrown for a simple reason that the keys are recreated. My question is how to detect whether a new fingerprint was added/deleted between 2 different runtimes?

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: _"for a simple reason that the keys are recreated"_ Why would you create a new key each time the app is restarted?

Answer (score 0):

On app startup you have to check if your keystore contains previously created key

```
 private var keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("AndroidKeyStore")
 private var cipher = Cipher.getInstance(...)

    init {
        try {
            keyStore.load(null)

            val key = keyStore.getKey(DEFAULT_KEY_NAME, null)

            if (key == null) {
                generateKey()
            }
        } catch (e: Throwable) {
            Timber.e(e)
        }
    }
```